# Evaluate thus limit using series: $\lim_{x\to0} (\sin x-\tan x)/x^3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

Evaluate thus limit using series:

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x-\tan x}{x^3}$$

I know the value of this limit is -1/2, and I also know the series expansion for $\sin x$ is $$x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + \cdots$$

I am having trouble being able to compute the limit. Is there another series that needs to be expanded out?

Comment: You will need the series expansion for $\tan x$. The full series is a mess, but you can get the terms up to the $x^3$ term without much difficulty by computing a few derivatives.

Comment: If the series is not known, you can also get it (without derivatives) from combining those of $\frac{1}{1+x}$, $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ (assuming you do know them to at least order $x^3$). Not necessarily faster, unless you're averse to derivatives.

Comment: to avoid making additional series computations, you could factor out $(\cos(x))^{-1}$, then use a trig identity, then use the Maclaurin series for $\sin(2x)$, but this would be taking some licence with the spirit of the question.

Comment: okay thank you very much was having trouble with this one

Answer (score 1):

Expand both $\sin$ and $\tan$: around $0$,
$$\begin{align}
\sin x &= x - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3) \\
\tan x &= x + \frac{x^3}{3} + o(x^3)
\end{align}$$
See below for more.

> $$\begin{align}\frac{\sin x - \tan x}{x^3} &= \frac{x - \frac{x^3}{6} - \left(x + \frac{x^3}{3}\right) + o(x^3)}{x^3} = \frac{-\frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^3}{6}  + o(x^3)}{x^3} = -\frac{1}{2} + o(1)\end{align}$$